Group SELECT from view Postgresql
I have two tables: tickets and ticket_messages. I need to create a report based on this two tables, so I created the following view:
CREATE VIEW report_users AS
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN t.date IS NOT NULL
            THEN t.date
        ELSE m.date
        END,

    CASE
        WHEN t.project_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN t.project_id
        ELSE m.project_id
        END,

    CASE
        WHEN t.user_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN t.user_id
        ELSE m.user_id
        END,

    CASE
        WHEN t.category_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN t.category_id
        ELSE m.category_id
        END,

    CASE
        WHEN t.channel_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN t.channel_id
        ELSE m.channel_id
        END,

    t.total_tickets
FROM
    (
      SELECT
        date_trunc('hour', t.created_at)
                             AS date,
        t.project_id,
        t.assignee_id        AS user_id,
        t.category_id,
        t.channel_id,
        COUNT(t.*)           AS total_tickets,
      FROM tickets t
      GROUP BY
        date,
        t.project_id,
        t.assignee_id,
        t.category_id,
        t.channel_id
    ) AS t

    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        date_trunc('hour', m.created_at)
                   AS date,
        t.project_id,
        m.user_id,
        t.category_id,
        t.channel_id,
        COUNT(m.*) AS total_messages
      FROM ticket_messages m
        JOIN tickets t ON t.id = m.ticket_id
      WHERE m.user_id IS NOT NULL
      GROUP BY
        date,
        t.project_id,
        m.user_id,
        t.category_id,
        t.channel_id
    ) AS m
      ON m.date = t.date
         AND m.project_id = t.project_id
         AND m.user_id = t.user_id
         AND m.category_id = t.category_id
         AND m.channel_id = t.channel_id;

I select report I need using the following query:
SELECT
    users.name AS "user",
    users.email As user_email,
    projects.name AS project,
    channels.title AS channel,
    rows.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        to_char(date_trunc('day', ru.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date,
        to_char(date_trunc('hour', ru.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24::MI::SS' ) AS date_hms,
        ru.user_id,
        ru.project_id,
        ru.category_id,
        ru.channel_id,

        SUM(ru.total_tickets) AS total_tickets
    FROM report_users ru
    WHERE
    ru.project_id = :project_id
    AND date_trunc('day', ru.date) >= to_date('2024-11-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND date_trunc('day', ru.date) <= to_date('2024-11-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    GROUP BY
        date,
        ru.user_id,
        ru.project_id,
        ru.channel_id,
        ru.category_id
    ) AS rows
LEFT OUTER JOIN projects ON projects.id = rows.project_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN channels ON channels.id = rows.channel_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = rows.user_id

ORDER BY
    date,
    "user",
    project,
    channel

With all above, result of query looks like this:



user
user_id
project
channel
date
total tickets




user_1
1
1
1
2024-11-12
1


user_1
1
1
1
2024-11-12
2



Problem:
Result is not grouped by user_id, although GROUP BY clause contains user_id field. I need to unite all rows with same user_id, but can't figure out how and what is the problem in y query.

offtopic: Instead of all these CASE statements, you can use COALESCE(). Much simpler. On topic: Check the view first. And without data it's hard to help you.

@FrankHeikens rigth, COALESCE fits there more. i will fix it. which data exactly do i need to add to make question more clear?

The GROUP BY is on an inner select (inside the FROM), what you want to do is to add a GROUP BY to the outer select!
It should look something like the following (I couldn't test it so you might have to play with it a bit):
SELECT
    users.name AS "user",
    users.email As user_email,
    string_agg(DISTINCT projects.name, ', ') AS projects,  --  <-- CHANGED
    string_agg(DISTINCT channels.title, ', ') AS channels, --  <-- CHANGED
    SUM(rows.*)                                            --  <-- CHANGED
FROM (
    SELECT
        to_char(date_trunc('day', ru.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date,
        to_char(date_trunc('hour', ru.date), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24::MI::SS' ) AS date_hms,
        ru.user_id,
        ru.project_id,
        ru.category_id,
        ru.channel_id,

        SUM(ru.total_tickets) AS total_tickets
    FROM report_users ru
    WHERE
    ru.project_id = :project_id
    AND date_trunc('day', ru.date) >= to_date('2024-11-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    AND date_trunc('day', ru.date) <= to_date('2024-11-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
    GROUP BY
        date,
        ru.user_id,
        ru.project_id,
        ru.channel_id,
        ru.category_id
    ) AS rows
LEFT OUTER JOIN projects ON projects.id = rows.project_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN channels ON channels.id = rows.channel_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON users.id = rows.user_id

GROUP BY                        -- <-- ADDED
    users.name,                 -- <-- ADDED
    users.email                 -- <-- ADDED

ORDER BY
    date,
    "user",
    project,
    channel

Keep in mind that "grouping" is done by the column, so if we'll have a look at the example you gave:



user
user_id
project
channel
date
total tickets




user_1
1
1
1
2024-11-12
1


user_1
1
1
1
2024-11-12
2



we can see that both rows have the same values in all the columns except the last one "total tickets" when we "group" we'll group all the columns in which we believe the values will be the same and usually want to SUM the other columns (or run an average or some other function).
So in this case if we would group by ALL the columns except the last one (and SUM the last one), we would get:



user
user_id
project
channel
date
total tickets




user_1
1
1
1.
2024-11-12
3



In the answer I suggested I assumed that projects/channels columns might have different values that we don't want to "SUM" but still aggregate hence the use of string_agg.
If you believe that all the columns of a user should be identical except the last one, I would not use string_agg and would do the grouping like this: GROUP BY 1,2,3,4 which means, grouping by the 1st parameter, than the second and etc (not including the last: the 5th!).

thaks for the options, just tried these.

don't really get it what you mean by SUM(rows.*). it gives a 'function does not exist' error.
tried group by on outer statement. it requires to add all fileds from the view and still don't group as expected


@invisiblecat did you copy exactly like I wrote: SUM(rows.*) or did you add a space between SUM and the parenthesis: SUM (rows.*) ? In regards to your first question I added an explanation at the bottom of the answer.
